# Play Music Runs Down Battery

Tags: google-play-music

NEVER listen to music on my Samsung Galaxy S2 phone, so it is annoying when my battery goes flat and I see that Google Play Music is somehow connected to the net. Like the other Google apps I don't use, I would like to, if not delete the app, at least stop it from running/updating whatever. I did see a similar question somewhere on the site but the recommended settings were not on my phone. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What Android version is that? At least you should be able to stop the app in `Settings` -> `Apps`.

Comment: How would I find out the version?

Comment: Again `Settings` -> `About`.

Comment: Found it! I hope. Model number:GT-19100; Android version:4.1.2; Baseband version :19100BULS3

Comment: When I go to settings I can't see an 'app' choice but I do see an App Manager. However, when I click on this and then Google Play Music, I can't see anything offered to delete/switch off/cancel updates and so on. As far as I can see, I cannot select Settings and then Apps

Comment: It would appear that a member eidolies made a contribution to this thread but I cannot find it because I have no idea as to how the site works. This is a fact, not a criticism.

Comment: Google play music is constantly running or updating. How can I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Play Music has come pre-installed on the phone. The only way to disable apps is going to Settings > App manager > All apps > Google Play Music   > Uninstall updates > Disable. Every android phone follow the same thing even though terminology used may be different. If you don't see Disable button then you need to root the phone to gain access as administrator.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm just a bit too old to try anything technical and because Play Music seems to be permanently updating, I might just change the phone. That said, I am sure that others with more go will be able to take advantage of your advice.

Comment: You could ask someone else to help you. Anyway I am always happy to help.